# In an Info Path 2013 form that links to SharePoint 2013 custom list -how to add a repeating table structure for only some columns and not all ?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, infopath, custom-list

I have created a SharePoint 2013 Custom list with several columns. I am designing an Info Path 2013 form for this custom list. When I click on checkbox manage multiple items (see inserted image).[image]

All the columns are grouped under a single group that can be added to a repeating table or a section. When I add it to the form and in the preview when I click on add row, it adds all the columns. I have about 10 columns in my sharepoint custom list. I want 4 columns out of these 10 in a repeating table. I am using Sharepoint 2013 and Info Path 2013 on Windows 7 Pro.

Is there a way to have only a subset of columns of the share point custom list in a info path form's repeating table?

I have tried editing the table by removing the columns and putting them else where, this doesn't solve the problem.

I have also tried right clicking on the field and un-checked the repeating check box. This didn't help either.

I tried creating the form first and then publishing to SharePoint custom list, but later learnt that this action is not allowed. I can only publish a form to SharePoint library.

Comment: First off i just wanted to find out if you need the Library to be a "Custom List"
library? Can you not create a Form Library? I know that List Libraries are not supported very well with regards to repeating tables.

Comment: I need this to be a custom-list. I am unsure of what you mean by "Custom List" Library -- a collection of custom lists? If so, yes. Would you please elaborate on the 'can you not create From Library?'